# you tube video not playing

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am new to android. I am trying play a youtube video whose path is present in an html file.. But when I do that I get black screen and upon tapping that a link will be displayed.. But I want the video to be displayed in my webview and on touching that video should be played..
I am using the following code..

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

WebSettings websets = webView.getSettings();

websets.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/youtubes.html");
```

any help on this ?

Thanks,
Keerthi

Comment: Are you playing them on a emulator or on a real phone

Answer (score 0):

YouTube usually requires flash. Are your links pointing to desktop version of YouTube? Do this links play in your browser in Android (not opening the YouTube app)?

Also take a look at m.youtube.com - this links are created to run on mobile devices by opening external player.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it on an emulator, then videos will not play from the youtube as you require flash. But if you are running it on a phone, then check if you added the methods properly or not. Also try using the VideoView class which takes the video source from your SD card. If it works, then it might be some problem with your code or if it doesnt works try installing any external player